# Request for a verification of a proof of concept related to data extraction on a pdf

Tags: pdf, data-extraction

The title might a little strong but I am currently trying to verify an assumption.

I have a two-column pdf containing various data (name, reference number, address, images) all associated with the same "entity" constructed as a register; each specific data is associated with a code (the code indicates the type of data). Each entity is separated from another one by a line.

As a result of data extraction, I would like to get a database (xls, access, json, XML...) in which each entity (one raw) is associated with its data (several columns) that I could use in various templates.

I am pretty sure that this is something that can be done but I am willing to know if this could be done easily by someone with no knowledge in scripting or if dedicated software might be useful (I tried nanonet without great success).

To show you what the pdf may look like, here is a jpg example (I deleted all personal data of course). If someone wants more detail or a full example (in pdf format), please let me know.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAGpO.jpg)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any way for me to send you a sample (pdf)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Not easy to recreate a pdf file without the data, so I had to transform the actual pdf into a word doc, make some changes and save as a new pdf. Any way, this pdf is exactly the kind od data I am looking to extract (text and image): https://docdro.id/FIww3gO Thanks for any tip or idea.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question. I guess each entity is part of a spreadsheet cell but then how could we explain that two columns have different heights of cells? Transforming the pdf into word might be more useful than trying to extract the data directly from the pdf? But then how to deal with the image (which won't be copied in the word doc)?